# How do I get the value of an object element inside an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array (print_r for formatting):

```
$result =  Array
(
    [link] => http://www.mysite.com/article/102758
    [type] => Article
    [title] => Sweetbay, PepsiCo Round the Bases
    [user] => <a href="/user/13208" title="View user profile.">pmalinowska</a> 
    [date] => 1306512291
    [node] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => dbcd60fee884/node/102758
            [nid] => 102758
            [uid] => 13208
            [title] => Sweetbay, PepsiCo Round the Bases
            [type] => article
            [created] => 1306412903
            [changed] => 1306512291
            [comment_count] => 0
            [name] => pmalinowska
            [url] => http://www.mysite.com/article/102758
            [path] => node/102758
            [score] => 1.2324483
        )
)
```

How would I grab the value of the created property of the node element? I've tried the following:

```
$result->node->created;

$result['node']['created'];

$result->node['created']
```

None of them work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

`$result[ "node" ]->created`

`$result` is an array while `$result[ "node" ]` is an object

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
`$result['node']->created`

Answer (score 2):

`$result['node']` is an object, so you must use [object member access syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).

So:

```
echo $result['node']->created;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think $result['node']->created;